# Сложение вещественных чисел

Tags: php, php7

В php складываю два вещественных числа длиной 7 знаков после запятой при выводе получаю что-то вроде 6.9Е-6, как вывести число нормально.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

Comment: спасибо помогло